# Update a row and delete another one

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm trying to update a table with values from another table. What I want to do is, each time an update happens, to delete the row in the table where I'm getting the data from.

This is my code so far:

```
UPDATE city SET city_longitude = (SELECT city_longitude FROM cities WHERE city.shortCity = cities.city_name OR city.cityName = cities.city_name LIMIT 1) LIMIT 100
```

This update is working so far, but I have to delete the rows where I'm updating FROM (the ones in the cities table).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to write stored-proc. or add a trigger.

Comment: just used a trigger and it gave me an error that it can't delete inside the trigger because the row is being used outside it (even tho i put the trigger AFTER UPDATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from cities where some_id = 1
```

Are you unable to do something along these lines after your UPDATE statement has finished? You may want to have something that actually confirms your UPDATE statement succeeded and then only DELETE afterwards.

The safer alternative is to have a flag called isUpdated or something along those lines, which you can set to true after an UPDATE but you keep the row in the original table.

Comment: can't do the first thing, but i'll take in consideration the flag setting if nothing else works